# LibGDX Cross Platform Networking

Tags: java, networking, libgdx, cross-platform

**Backstory:**
I've been developing a game with LibGDX for the past two years, and I've seen it refactored more times than I remember.

I jumped on the iOS iKVM port as soon as it was released.
But I've been struggling with it ever since in regards to cross platform networking. 
Kryonet will not port over to iOS unfortunately. So it's either I ditch Kryonet, or lose a large chunk of my target audience (iOS Users)

**My question for you is:** 
I noticed LibGDX has cross platform classes ready for sockets and HTTP Requests, but no documentation exists for these sockets at all.

Has anyone used these sockets at all in the past, and does anyone know how they work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bit of documentation on the `Net` package that gives a very brief overview:
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.html  The [`Net.HttpRequest` doc](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Net.HttpRequest.html) covers the http setup in a bit more detail.

The http API is based on callbacks to listeners that handle results or failures.  The raw Socket API provides stream-oriented access to connection data.